# Getting error when install ionic in linux mint

Tags: ionic-framework

I have tried a lot. But getting the same error when i tried to install Ionic.

I have tried this command

```
sudo ionic start lottery-app  tabs --type=angular
```

And getting this error. Even i tried with Sudo. But still getting the same permission issue.

```
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /var/www/html/ionic/lottery-app/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/html/ionic/lottery-app/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.8.0-53-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/var/www/html/ionic/lottery-app/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/html/ionic/lottery-app/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

and after that how can i run this like mobile App by Android SDK.Please help me i am totally new in it. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i was also getting many error while install it in ubuntu

try this script i found online on github this install ionic perfectly
[click here](https://github.com/itsvinayak/books/blob/master/linux%20scripts%20and%20software/ubuntu_ionic_installer.sh)